# Whats the best representation of variables with large uncertainty

Tags: standard-deviation, uncertainty

When express results with uncertainty it's common that sometimes these uncertainty pass the limit allowed of the variable.

For example, training a classificator model with an expected accuracy we usually express this accuracy with uncertainty using the mean and standard deviation of the accuracy of the many models evaluated in different test samples and trained in different train samples. The problem is when the sum of the mean and the standard deviation is larger than the limit of the variable with, for accuracy is between $0$ and $1$.

To vizualize this let's consider a set of models with the mean accuracy of $0.95$ and standard deviation of $0.10$. We can't express the accuracy with uncertainty as $0.95\pm0.10$ because this way the uncertainty pass the limit of $1$.

What's the best way to represent uncertainty in that case?

Comment: Questions in the SE system are supposed to be narrow & 
concrete such that they can be given a definitively 
correct, factual answer in at  most a few paragraphs. 
This isn't a site for discussions or opinions.

Comment: Are you getting that uncertainty in the classification accuracy by doing something related to a t-distribution?

Comment: No, nothing like t-distribution, more like I'm using cross validation to train a model to classify the instances of a dataset

Comment: I'm not trying to discuss or show my opinion, I'm looking for a tool to represent uncertainty rather than standard deviation to use it when standard deviation show its limitation. Sorry if I formulated the question wrong

Comment: How do you get $\pm 0.10?$

Comment: That was just an example, the accuracy in that case is a random variable with mean $0.95$, standard deviation of $0.10$ and that must be between $0$ and $1$